# How to get asp hidden field value of another page via iframe

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am developing an application in asp.net using c#. In my application there are two pages like `abc.aspx` and `xyz.aspx`. I am opening the `xyz.aspx` page in an `iframe` of `abc.aspx`.

In `xyz.aspx` page I have a asp hidden field named `ht_test_access`. Now my requirement is I have to access the value of that hidden field from `abc.aspx` directly without querystring, session, cookies etc. Please help.

Comment: I tried this before but you cannot do it because of CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing). However, have you tried storing the data in the localstorage?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Button.PostBackUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl.aspx) and use [Page.PreviousPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx) to get the previous page form data. This MSDN article [Cross-Page Posting in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178139%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) explains it very well.

```
string text = ((HiddenField)PreviousPage.FindControl("hdnField")).Value;
```

> [Cross-page posting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x3x8t37x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is similar to hyperlinks in that the transfer is
>   initiated by a user action. However, in cross-page posting, the target
>   page is invoked using an HTTP POST command, which sends the values of
>   controls on the source page to the target page. In addition, if the
>   source and target page are in the same Web application, the target
>   page can access public properties of the source page. As always, all
>   of the pages in the application can share information stored in
>   session state or application state.